# Converting a string to an already defined variable name in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I am looking to write a query, for example

```
hello_world<- c(1,2,3,4)
hi_world <- c(5,6,7)

x<- c(paste("hello","world",sep="_"),paste("hi","world",sep="_"))
```

I have stored the previously defined variable names as string inside the variable x

Now from x, how can I call out the any of the 2 variables so that it displays

```
5 6 7
```

If I call x[2] which is actually hi_world?

Comment: Ok, I got it from an older post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971844/access-variable-value-where-the-name-of-variable-is-stored-in-a-string-in-r

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but if you're just getting started with R, please be aware that relying on `get` is a bad habit, particularly for inexperienced R programmers. It will often lead to code patterns that are quite problematic.

Comment: Joran - is there a more cleaner way to do this? If you can please guide

Comment: A more standard pattern would be to put your vectors in a named list: `my_list <- list(hello_world = 1:4,hi_world = 5:7)`. Then you can do `my_list[[x[1]]]`. The main problem with `get` is that eventually you're going to want to use it to retrieve an object _and_ assign a new value to it, and that generally won't work.