# Dynamically Extract Name from List

Tags: r, lm

What's the proper way to extract a variable by name from a list dynamically without altering the underlying data type? I originally thought I could do it with `thelist[varname]`, but the bracket operation always mangles the value into a list. Below is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
names(df) <- c('x','y','z')
lms = list(
  lm1 = lm(y ~ x, data = df),
  lm2 = lm(z ~ x, data = df)
)

class(lms$lm1) # => lm
class(lms['lm1']) # => list
```

Comment: `class(lms[['lm1']])`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971844/access-variable-value-where-the-name-of-variable-is-stored-in-a-string-in-r/3972827#3972827