# How to join to variables to access to list in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 variables, and a list. I want to use the two variables to access to the list files, but I don´t know how to deal with it.

Imagien that I have this:

```
data <- list()
data$one <- "first"
```

And that I have 2 variables, var1, and var2:

```
var1 <- "data"
var2 <- "one"
```

How can I use this variables to access to data$one?

I have tried with:

```
get(paste0(var1,"$",var2))
```

But I get an error:

```
Error in get(paste0(var1,"$",var2)): object data$one not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access variable value where the name of variable is stored in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971844/access-variable-value-where-the-name-of-variable-is-stored-in-a-string)

Comment: `get(var1)[[var2]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @markus pointed out,

```
get(var1)[[var2]]
# [1] "first"
```

works as needed.

I guess what's equally important is why your approach didn't work. While

```
paste0(var1,"$",var2)
# [1] "data$one"
```

correctly *describes* what you are interested in, `data$one` itself is not a variable, it's a result of a function call, which can also be written as:

```
`$`(data, one)
# [1] "first"
```

Now it somewhat makes sense that something like

```
get("`$`(data, one)")
# Error in get("`$`(data, one)") : object '`$`(data, one)' not found
```

shouldn't work, just like

```
get("2 + 2")
# Error in get("2 + 2") : object '2 + 2' not found
```