# R how can I comment a variable through its string name?

Tags: r

```
x <- "y"
assign(x,4)

comment(get(x))<-"this is a comment!"
```

how can i do something like this? 
i tried also

```
comment(x) <-"this is a comment!"
```

and my others, but it doesn't seem to work.
Similar to this question: [Access variable value where the name of variable is stored in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971844/access-variable-value-where-the-name-of-variable-is-stored-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary variable and then re-assign it:

```
x <- "y"
assign(x,4)
temp_x <- get(x)
comment(temp_x) <- "this is a comment!"
assign(x, temp_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval(
  substitute(
    expr = comment(temp) <- "this is a comment!",
    env = list(temp = as.name(x))
  )
)

str(y)
```

**Output:**

```
 num 4
 - attr(*, "comment")= chr "this is a comment!"
```