# Using a character vector to refer to a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I want to refer to a data frame by using a character vector.

I believe the simple example below illustrates the problem.

```
# I have a data frame called A
A <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)

# I have a character vector called B, containing the character "A"
B <- "A"

# Now I want a third vector (C) to get the content of A, simply by referring to vector B 
# Obviously, I cannot write
C <- B 
# ... as this would give me 
[1] "A"

# ... and NOT what I want:
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

How do I use a character vector to refer to the name *and thus the content* of an existing data frame?

PS.
I have been made aware of my questiong being a duplicate. But since the wordings are different, I didn't find the other post when searching online:
[Access variable value where the name of variable is stored in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971844/access-variable-value-where-the-name-of-variable-is-stored-in-a-string)
I keep my post, as others too might fail to find the earlier one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be `get` to return the value of the object name as string

```
C <- get(B)
```

If there are more than objects, use `mget` to return the values in a `list`