# print value of variables in R from ls()

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R from another programming language. I am trying to print or pass the value of athe variables present in the envi in R

`for (value in ls()) { print("the value is:" value) }`

This prints the varible name instead of the value present in the variable, i understand why it is doing it but what is the way to print the value in the variable or pass that value to another variable using ls()

`for (value in ls()) { print("the value is:" value) }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access variable value where the name of variable is stored in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971844/access-variable-value-where-the-name-of-variable-is-stored-in-a-string) - use `get(value)`. Also the syntax of your print statement is wrong, you need a comma and `print()` doesn't concatenate arguments. You want `print(paste("the value is:", get(value)))` or `message("the value is: ", get(value))`

Answer (score 0):

`parse()` converts characters to an expression and `eval()` evaluates said expression. Addmitedly, I don't know to explain better than this as I'm not an advanced user of R myself, but I do know that it works

```
# With a clean environment
a = 1
b = 2

for (value in ls()) { 
  print(paste0("the value is: " ,eval(parse(text = value)))) 
  
  }
[1] "the value is: 1"
[1] "the value is: 2"
```